# Getting all user data using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: office365api, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-api

Using PHP and the Microsoft Graph API I'm fetching a user by querying:

`https://graph.windows.net/<tenant>/users/<userId>?api-version=2013-11-08`

This works fine, but only returns the standard fields for the user object. According to the documentation I'm supposed to be able to use $select=* to get all the user data, like this:

`https://graph.windows.net/<tenant>/users/<userId>?$select=*&api-version=2013-11-08`

However this gives me the following error:
`{"odata.error":{"code":"Request_BadRequest","message":{"lang":"en","value":"The ability to use the $select query option to define a projection in a data service query is disabled. To enable this functionality, set the DataServiceConfiguration. AcceptProjectionRequests property to true."}}}`

How can I enable "AcceptProjectionRequests"? I find nothing about this in the documentation or in other SO-threads.

Comment: The Graph API supports the following Odata query parameters:`$filter,$batch,$expand,$orderby,$top,$skiptoken and previous-page`. Refer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-operations-overview#OdataQueryParameters)

Answer (score 3):

The APIs you are referencing above are Azure AD Graph which is different than the [Microsoft Graph APIs](https://graph.microsoft.io). It might be worth your time to have a look at the Microsoft Graph APIs and consider transitioning away from Azure AD Graph. The general guidance from the Azure AD Graph team recommends using the Microsoft Graph instead of the Azure AD Graph. You can read more about the differences and the Azure AD guidance [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aadgraphteam/2016/07/08/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph/).

Having said that, Azure AD Graph does not support $select (as stated in the blog posting I linked to above). Microsoft Graph does support $select for doing query projections (see [Microsoft Graph or Azure AD](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aadgraphteam/2016/07/08/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph/)).

> Currently (as of 7/8/2016) Microsoft Graph supports most of the directory features that Azure AD Graph supports, but not all.  In some cases, Microsoft Graph supports functionality that is not in Azure AD Graph (such as ability to make $select projection queries).

Per OData spec, $select=* can either return all entity properties or a default set of properties (provided the default set contains all key properties). The Microsoft Graph implementation is the latter and it will return a set of key properties. In order to get all the necessary properties you need, you will need to explicitly request the entire list you want unless they happen to be within the default set.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that it will not be possible to retrieve custom fields from AD using Azure AD Graph, and that we have to move over to Microsoft Graph API?

Comment: Extension / custom properties should be returned in an object GET request as part of the default set of properties on the object when using Azure AD Graph APIs.

Comment: None of the custom properties are returned, it seems like the Azure AD Graph API only returns the default set. This is when querying https://graph.windows.net/<tenant>/users/<userId>

Comment: Can you be explicit about what you mean by a custom property and how you created it please? Hopefully we can get to the bottom of this. Robert's observations (to this point) are accurate for both AAD and Microsoft Graph. To reiterate, AAD Graph will return ALL properties of the user, including any directory schema extension properties per this topic: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-directory-schema-extensions.